# Compile Izpack 5.0 installer with java 11 succesfully then fails to execute. If compiled with java 1.8 executes succesfully

Tags: java, izpack

Here is the output from "java -jar app_install.jar" using java 11 which is what was used to compile. When compiled with java 1.8 there is no issue, and need this to be using java 11. IzPack version is 5.0.

> Can't load log handler
> "com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandler"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandlerjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandlerat
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.createLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:1000)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:970)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:966)at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:966)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1199)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:525)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:515)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:654)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:717)at
> java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:701)at
> com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer.initializeLogging(Installer.java:108)at
> com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer.main(Installer.java:75)Exception
> in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/izforge/izpack/util/Debugat
> com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer.initializeLogging(Installer.java:110)at
> com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer.main(Installer.java:75)Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.izforge.izpack.util.Debugat
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)... 2
> more

Tried compiling with java 1.8 and java 11, both show to compile and create the jar. Issue is when executing the jar when java is set to java 11.

Comment: Out of interest why are you using a third party installer when the JDK itself supports [creating installers](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9)?